# How to calculate flow rate from a pressure sealed flask and a small tube?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, flow

We have Flask under known, regulated pressure. Flask diameter is known and is cylindrical shape . We know the volume of the medium inside. At the bottom at the flask is a tube with known diameter and length. We know the density of the medium inside the flask.

Summary of known data:

- Pressure **p**
- Flask diameter **d<sub>f</sub>**
- Flask is **cylindrical shape**
- Medium volume  **V** and density **ρ**
- Tube diameter **d<sub>t</sub>** and length **l<sub>t</sub>**
- One **end of tube is in flask medium** and another is in flask with **atmospheric pressure**

Is it possible to calculate the flow rate for a given time range t with this information?

[image: Example]

Comment: What do you mean by 'flash' and what's the function of the air?

Comment: Oh, I see, you meant 'flask', of course.

Comment: Honey vs water will display different flow rates..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rate of flow through the tube can be approximated by the [Hagen–Poiseuille equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hagen%E2%80%93Poiseuille_equation#Equation):

$$\boxed{\Delta p=\frac{8\mu LQ}{\pi R^4}}$$

where:

- $Δp$ is the pressure difference between the two ends, that is $\Delta p=p-p_{atm}$ (neglecting the hydrostatic pressure),
- $L$ is the length of pipe,
- $μ$ is the dynamic viscosity,
- $Q$ is the volumetric flow rate,
- $R$ is the pipe radius.